# subtracting posixCT objects and not getting seconds

Tags: r, timing

I'm getting weird units after I subtract `POSIXct` objects, which are returned from two calls to `Sys.time()`. I'm using `Sys.time()` to time some call to `system()`--something like this:

```
start <- Sys.time()
system("./something_complicated_that_takes_a_while")
end <- Sys.time()
cat(end - start, "seconds\n")
```

I get `1.81494815872775 seconds`, which is very strange. The runtime was closer to 1.8 **hours**, though. Just to check, I can do this:

```
start <- Sys.time()
system("/bin/sleep 2")
end <- Sys.time()
cat(end - start, "seconds\n")
```

and I get `2.002262 seconds`, so it's working fine here. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Try this: ` y <- Sys.time();  y-x;  y <- y+3600; y-x ; y <- y+3600*24 ; y-x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code is ok , it is 1.8 hours not seconds , here is explanation

```
a <- Sys.time()

b <- Sys.time() + 2 * 60 *60 # i add 2 hours here

b - a 

#> Time difference of 2.000352 hours
```

above the deference `b - a` gives the answer in hours not seconds , so if you want to use `cat` try

```
cat(b-a  , attr(b - a , "units"))

#> 2.000352 hours
```

and if you want your output in seconds try this

```
difftime(b , a , units = "secs")

#> Time difference of 7201.266 secs
```